# will_paginate on Ruby on Rails 3.2 with multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

My rails application connects to a mysql db, but in one single model ("Customer") I use a different sql server database. My app works fine, I can get all the customers with `Customer.all`, but when I try to add pagination I get this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'mysql_database.Customers' doesn't exist: SHOW CREATE TABLE `Customers`
```

For some reason, will_paginate is searching the table in my main database (mysql) instead of the sql server db.

In my CustomersController, I have this:

```rb
def index
  @customers = Customer.paginate :page=>params[:page], :order=>'name1, name2 asc',
      :per_page => 20

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @customers }
  end
end
```

And this is my SQL Server model, which connects to mssql_db

```rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :CustomerCode

  alias_attribute :id, :CustomerCode

  has_many :tickets

  establish_connection Rails.configuration.database_configuration["mssql_db"] 
end
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: try just to use self.per_page = 10 in your model

Comment: If I put `self.per_page = 10` in my model and I leave `@customers = Customer.paginate :page=>params[:page]` in the controller, nothing changes

Comment: i think it can help you to solve your issue

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter